# MSYS2 - makepkg error pkgname not allowed to begin with a hyphen

Tags: tesseract, msys, msys2

I'm trying to build tesseract on msys2, and I'm following the directions here:

[tesseract compiling instructions](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling)

I've installed the dependencies listed there, and I've created the PKGBUILD file that's provided in the link above. WHen I run makepkg, I get the error:

> ==> ERROR: pkgname is not allowed to start with a hyphen.

I'm not sure what's going on here. Can anybody help? Apologies if this is a bit basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **makepkg-mingw** for creating packages from mingw-w64 PKGBUILDs (pkgbase starts with mingw-w64-${_realname}).